# Enumerating over a enum that defines months in the year

Tags: c#

I have some code that allows me to enumerate over months in a year.  This code is used both in a Web application as well as a standalone exe.  Although it doesn't have to be efficient it is used a lot so if there are any improvements that would be great (I haven't done any profiling).  It also needs to be thread-safe.

```
public enum MonthEnum
{
    Undefined, // Required here even though it's not a valid month
    January,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May,
    June,
    July,
    August,
    September,
    October,
    November,
    December
}

public static class MonthEnumEnumerator
{
    private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<MonthEnum> MonthsInYear = CreateYear();
    private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<MonthEnum> ReversedMonthsInYear = CreateYear(janToDec: false);

    private static ReadOnlyCollection<MonthEnum> CreateYear(bool janToDec = true)
    {
        var months = new List<MonthEnum>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            months.Add((MonthEnum)i);

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<MonthEnum>(janToDec ? months : months.OrderByDescending(p => (int)p).ToList());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an array of MonthEnums without the MonthEnum.Undefined value
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<MonthEnum> GetValues()
    {
        return MonthsInYear;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an array of Months starting from December to January not including the Undefined value
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<MonthEnum> GetValuesReversed()
    {
        return ReversedMonthsInYear;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of months in range of start and end.  For example with a start month of Feb and end of April this function
    /// would return Feb, March, April.  If the start month was Nov and end Month Feb it would return Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">Start of month range to return</param>
    /// <param name="end">End of month range to return</param>
    /// <returns>Array of months in order from start to end</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<MonthEnum> GetInRange(MonthEnum start, MonthEnum end)
    {
        var range = new List<MonthEnum>();

        if(start <= end)
        {
            // simple start to end of months with no december rollover                
            for(MonthEnum month = start; month <= end; month++)
                range.Add(month);
        }
        else
        {
            //  end month wraps around december i.e. Nov - Feb
            for (MonthEnum month = start; month <= MonthEnum.December; month++)
                range.Add(month);

            // now jan - end month
            for (MonthEnum month = MonthEnum.January; month <= end; month++)
                range.Add(month);
        }

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<MonthEnum>(range);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MonthEnum> GetInRange(MonthEnum start)
    {
        return GetInRange(start, start.Previous());
    }

    public static MonthEnum Next(this MonthEnum month)
    {
        return month == MonthEnum.December ? MonthEnum.January : month + 1;
    }

    public static MonthEnum Previous(this MonthEnum month)
    {
        return month == MonthEnum.January ? MonthEnum.December : month - 1;
    }

    public static MonthEnum Subtract(this MonthEnum month, int months)
    {
        MonthEnum subtracted = month;

        while ((months--) > 0)
            subtracted = subtracted.Previous();

        return subtracted;
    }

    public static MonthEnum Add(this MonthEnum month, int months)
    {
        MonthEnum added = month;

        while ((months--) > 0)
            added = added.Next();

        return added;
    }
}
```

I use it like so:

```
foreach (var month in MonthEnumEnumerator.GetValues())
{
    // do stuff that is month related
}
```

or

```
// for getting the months from July to December
foreach (var month in MonthEnumEnumerator.GetInRange(MonthEnum.July, MonthEnum.December))
{
   // do something
}
```

or if I want to get the previous month to what I'm on I can do

```
var previousMonth = currentMonth.Previous();
```

UPDATE:
I updated my answer after comments/answers below.

Comment: Is there a reason why `Undefined` is required? Couldn't you just use `January = 1`?

Comment: Yes, the enumeration is serialized as part of an XML document and it is an optional field. We didn't know how else to show that so included an Undefined (It's serialized as empty string). It's littered through code modules so to move it out with be to much of a major at this point.

Comment: In that case, I think it would make more sense to remove `Undefined` and use `MonthEnum?` instead, but I understand that you can't change that now.

Comment: Never thought to use a MonthEnum?.  Will have to try that out in our serialization process and put it down as a possible refactor later.  cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out what the purpose of `janToDec` was. Given that you're using Linq, I can't see any reason not to just implement `ReversedMonthsInYear` as

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<MonthEnum> ReversedMonthsInYear = MonthsInYear.Reverse();
```

IMO that's a lot easier on the maintenance programmer.

But then `CreateYear` without the parameter is simply duplicating code, and you can eliminate it in favour of

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<MonthEnum> MonthsInYear = GetInRange(MonthEnum.January, MonthEnum.December);
```

---

Since you're not afraid to use arithmetic on your enum, you can make `Subtract` and `Add` a bit less loopy.

```
public static MonthEnum Subtract(this MonthEnum month, int months)
{
    if (months < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("months", "months must be non-negative");

    MonthEnum subtracted = month - (months % 12);
    if (subtracted < MonthEnum.January) subtracted += 12;
    return subtracted;
}
```

and similarly.

Comment: Yes, getting rid of the loops seems like a good idea.

Comment: I like the idea of having ReversedMonthsInYear = MonthsInYear.Reverse() but then this means that we need to ensure that MonthsInYear is always called before ReversedMonthsInYear when constructing.  Is that a good dependency to have?

Comment: @dreza, if you're worried about that you can always create a static initialiser to force the initialisation order.

Comment: Excellent.  Yes that would be a preferred solution I think.  Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

First allow me to comment on the current implementation.

- `Undefined` is a poor name for a default value, particularly with an enum. Undefined could mean many things in many different contexts. I'd avoid using it. A better name would be `None` as its value doesn't represent a month but nothing.
- The name of the enum itself is also poor. Hungarian notation, especially in a class name is just a terrible idea. We don't need the name of the enum to tell us it is an enum. Let the IDE or documentation tell us that.  Just name it `Month`.
- A common naming convention that I would suggest adopting would be to name your extension classes as `[ClassItsExtending]Extensions`.
- There are way too many things wrong with your `MonthEnumEnumerator` implementation.  Since the point of the class is to generate enumerators to enumerate over, return instances of `IEnumerable<Month>`, not `IList<Month>`.  By doing so, you're implicitly telling the user that the list is modifiable.  That compounded by the fact that you're returning the internal list directly, you're just asking for trouble.

---

I was debating whether this would be more useful as a `struct` or an `enum`, considering all the operations you were trying to add to it.  A struct would have been a safer bet.  However enums are much more lightweight and the way you're using it, it doesn't need to be more complicated than that.

```
public enum Month
{
    None,
    January,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May,
    June,
    July,
    August,
    September,
    October,
    November,
    December,
}
```

There are many improvements to be made.  If you think of the months as indexes, it will simplify everything.  You shouldn't have to loop n times just to figure out what the n'th month is after January, a simple addition should be enough.  By doing this, this will allow you to remove many of the redundant operations that you currently have.

First let's start with the extensions:

```
public static class MonthExtensions
{
    public static Month FromIndex(int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
            return Month.None;
        else if (index > 0)
            return (Month)(((index - 1) % 12) + 1);
        else // if (index < 0)
            return (Month)(12 - (Math.Abs(index + 1) % 12));
    }

    public static int ToIndex(this Month month)
    {
        return (int)month;
    }

    public static Month Add(this Month month, int months)
    {
        if (months == 0)
            return month;

        var newIndex = ToIndex(month) + months;
        // need to offset the "None" year
        if (newIndex < 1 && month != Month.None) newIndex = newIndex - 1;
        return FromIndex(newIndex);
    }

    public static Month Next(this Month month)
    {
        return Add(month, 1);
    }

    public static Month Previous(this Month month)
    {
        return Add(month, -1);
    }
}
```

When looking at months as indexes, you can take advantage that wrapping will be taken care of automatically.  So with this, you don't even need to have a `Subtract()` method, `Add()` could be used and accepts negative numbers.  This works nicely as it is similar to the `DateTime` methods available.

It would be cleaner if you have your enumerable methods in a separate class from your extensions.  With this new "indexing" scheme, this simplifies everything and you can make better use of LINQ.

```
public static class MonthEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<Month> YearAscending()
    {
        return RangeAscending(1, 12);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Month> YearDescending()
    {
        return RangeDescending(1, 12);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Month> Range(Month start)
    {
        return Range(start, start.Previous());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Month> Range(Month start, Month end)
    {
        if (start == Month.None)
            return Enumerable.Empty<Month>();
        else if (start <= end)
            return RangeAscending(start.ToIndex(), end.ToIndex());
        else
            return RangeAscending(start.ToIndex(), end.ToIndex() + 12);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Month> RangeAscending(int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        return Range(startIndex, endIndex, i => MonthExtensions.FromIndex(i));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Month> RangeDescending(int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        return Range(startIndex, endIndex, i => MonthExtensions.FromIndex(-i));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Month> Range(int startIndex, int endIndex,
            Func<int, Month> monthSelector)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1)
            .Select(monthSelector);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note.  You may have seen a previous post where I return IList.  I edited the question so the items return IEnumerable instead.

Comment: Also, I agree with the naming conventions but this code is following the conventions of the project so IMHO it's better to stick with project naming conventions rather than apparent "best practices".

Comment: I'm also not sure if I see the point in recalculating the YearAscending and YearDescending values when they will not change once worked out once?

Comment: There's no point in keeping around a small collection of values either, especially when the values can be generated in constant time. Besides, there is no "calculations" being performed here. LINQ queries create generators. The only calculations being performed are done only when you enumerate over the collection but all we're doing here ultimately is mapping a number to another value which is trivial. If you can measure a noticeable performance hit, then by all means, do what you must. But you shouldn't concern yourself with that until you have evidence to say that this isn't fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take - note the `ReadOnlyCollection` creations to keep the callers from being able to modify the members of the static collection:

```
public enum Month
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required here even though it's not a valid month.
    /// </summary>
    Undefined,

    January,

    February,

    March,

    April,

    May,

    June,

    July,

    August,

    September,

    October,

    November,

    December
}

public static class MonthEnumerator
{
    private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Month> monthsInYear = new ReadOnlyCollection<Month>(
        Enumerable.Range((int)Month.January, (int)Month.December).Cast<Month>().ToList());

    private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Month> reversedMonthsInYear = new ReadOnlyCollection<Month>(
        monthsInYear.Reverse().ToList());

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerable of MonthEnums without the Month.Undefined value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Month> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return monthsInYear;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerable of Months starting from December to January not including the Undefined value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Month> ReversedValues
    {
        get
        {
            return reversedMonthsInYear;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Month> GetInRange(Month start, Month end)
    {
        var range = new List<Month>();

        if (start <= end)
        {
            // Simple start to end of months with no December rollover.
            for (var month = start; month <= end; month++)
            {
                range.Add(month);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // End month wraps around December i.e. Nov - Feb.
            for (var month = start; month <= Month.December; month++)
            {
                range.Add(month);
            }

            // Now Jan - end month.
            for (var month = Month.January; month <= end; month++)
            {
                range.Add(month);
            }
        }

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<Month>(range);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Month> GetInRange(Month start)
    {
        return GetInRange(start, start.Previous());
    }

    public static Month Next(this Month month)
    {
        return month == Month.December ? Month.January : month + 1;
    }

    public static Month Previous(this Month month)
    {
        return month == Month.January ? Month.December : month - 1;
    }

    public static Month Subtract(this Month month, int months)
    {
        var subtracted = month;

        while (months-- > 0)
        {
            subtracted = subtracted.Previous();
        }

        return subtracted;
    }

    public static Month Add(this Month month, int months)
    {
        var added = month;

        while (months-- > 0)
        {
            added = added.Next();
        }

        return added;
    }
}
```

Use as:

```
foreach (var month in MonthEnumerator.Values)
{
    // Do stuff that is month related.
    Console.WriteLine(month);
}

Console.WriteLine();

// For getting the months from July to December.
foreach (var month in MonthEnumerator.GetInRange(Month.July, Month.December))
{
    // Do something.
    Console.WriteLine(month);
}

Console.WriteLine();

var currentMonth = Month.May;
var previousMonth = currentMonth.Previous();
Console.WriteLine(previousMonth);
```

Comment: In the case of Values and ReversedValues is a new collection created on every get?  If so do we need to make a new instance each time given the underlying values will never change?  static stuff still catches me out a bit...

Comment: @dreza Yes, it would. I think a better solution would be to keep the `ReadOnlyCollection`s in the fields.

Comment: @Jess One question.  Is making Getvalues() a property of Values a style/preference thing here or is the concept/abstraction of the access important in this case.  Just trying to understand the reasoning.  cheers.

Comment: @dreza to your first comment: yes, because the caller could always cast it back to a `List<T>` and mutate the contents. A new instance keeps the original completely intact. As to your second comment: it is a style/preference thing. It kinda looked like a duck and quacked like a duck when I saw it, so I changed it to a duck (property).

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer LOL duck.  I did do a quick search and ToList() creates a new copy of the list so in this instance as the underlying objects are not reference types you wouldn't be modifying the underlying contents.  I actually realized that I missed a unit test for this case so added one in just to be sure.

Comment: @dreza I thought I had read somewhere that `ToList()` will just return the list itself if the underlying type is `List<T>` already. But I'm using Reflector on the extension method and it looks like it effectively winds up calling `Array.CopyTo()` internally.